# Why Swift generic constraints seem to work inconsistently in this example?

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to write some generic functions in Swift, with versions constrained to optionals, but I'm running into behavior that is surprising to me.

Consider the following code (tested in a playground):

```
public protocol OptionalType {}
extension Optional: OptionalType {}

func asOptional<T>(_ t: T) -> T? { return t }
func asOptional<T>(_ t: T) -> T where T: OptionalType { return t }

class C {}

let c = C()
print(type(of: c))   //  #1 - C
print(type(of: asOptional(c)))   //  #2 - Optional<C>

let optc: C? = C()
print(type(of: optc))   //  #3 - Optional<C>
print(type(of: asOptional(optc)))   //  #4 - Optional<C>

func foo<T>(_ t: T) {
    print(type(of: t))   //  #5 - Optional<C>
    print(type(of: t) == type(of: optc))   //  #6 - true
    print(type(of: asOptional(t)))   //  #7 - Optional<Optional<C>> -- why?
}
foo(optc)
```

Why don't #4 and #7 print the same? To me it seems that the asOptional() call at #7 should call the constrained version, just like the call at #4 does (after all, the types of `t` and `optc` are the same, as checked on the previous line). Why not?

Comment: If `t` is optional in `#5`, then shouldn't it be double optional in `#7`? You are printing optional as optional, the double optional is the expected value.

Comment: Which Swift version are you using?

Comment: @SavcaMarin If double optional was expected, then it would also be expected at #4 (`optc` is also optional, just like `t`). But at #4 the second variant of asOptional() gets called, and that avoids the double optional. I don't see why the same isn't happening at #7.

Comment: @PGDev Swift 5 (but I'll check with Swift 4 too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolution between your two overloads of `asOptional()` is done at *compile* time using the type information available at that time.

The `print` output is showing you the *runtime* type.

For #4 the type of `optc` is known to be `Optional<C>` at compile time, which conforms to `OptionalType`, and so the compiler selects the second overload of `asOptional()`.

For #7 the type of `t` is *only* known to be *some type* `T` at compile time, so the compiler must select the first overload of `asOptional()`, which results in the double optional result at runtime if `t` has an optional type.

HTH

Comment: Oh, I see. Apparently C++ templates are tripping me up. I think in C++ the compiler would generate a foo<Optional<C>>(), and from that the second asOptional() would get called. I assumed Swift would work in a similar way.

Comment: @imre - C++ templates and Swift generics work quite differently despite being used for many similar purposes. C# and Swift have similar approaches, Java is closer to these two than C++ but also has important differences. Search for C#/Swift generics vs. C++ comparisons, there are useful questions on SO, for more details. HTH

Answer (score 2):

In 1st case,

```
print(type(of: asOptional(optc)))   //  #4 - Optional<C>
```

Since `optc` is an `Optional` type, so `func asOptional<T>(_ t: T) -> T where T: OptionalType` method is called which returns a *non-optional* value. So the result is a *single optional*.

Instead in the 2nd case,

```
func foo<T>(_ t: T) {
    //....
    print(type(of: asOptional(t)))   //  #7 - Optional<Optional<C>> -- why?
}
```

Since `t` is a *non-optional* type, so`func asOptional<T>(_ t: T) -> T?` method is called which return an *optional value*. That's why `t` is wrapped in another `optional` hence giving a *double optional value*.

Comment: I guess you mean `t` (not `optc`) is a non-optional type in the 2nd case, right? Yes, that's where I got confused, because my prints said that it's optional. But as @CRD's answer explains, only `t`'s _runtime_ type is optional, but its _compile-time_ type (used for overload resolution) is non-optional.